# How to use Spring bean in JasperReport Expression?

Tags: spring, jasper-reports

how we can use the **spring bean** in  **JasperReport expression** to call the method of that bean? as i have implemented, we can call the static methods by adding the **jar** file to the class path but what if methods are not static?